# How to run ansible playbook from github actions - without using external action

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, github-actions

I have written a workflow file, that prepares the runner to connect to the desired server with ssh, so that I can run an ansible playbook.

`ssh -t -v theUser@theHost` shows me that the SSH connection works.

The ansible sript however tells me, that the sudo Password is missing.

If I leave the line `ssh -t -v theUser@theHost` out, ansible throws a connection timeout and cant connect to the server.

=>  `fatal: [***]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host *** port 22: Connection timed out`

**First I don't understand, why ansible can connect to the server only if i execute the command** `ssh -t -v theUser@theHost`.

The **next problem** is, that the user does not need any sudo Password to have execution rights. The same ansible playbook works very well from my local machine without using the sudo password. I configured the server, so that the user has enough rights in the desired folder recursively.

It simply doesn't work form my GithHub Action.
Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

My workflow file looks like this:

```
name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
  
# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  run-playbooks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          token: ${{secrets.REPO_TOKEN}}
      - name: Run Ansible Playbook
        run: |
         mkdir -p /home/runner/.ssh/
         touch /home/runner/.ssh/config
         touch /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
         echo -e "${{secrets.SSH_KEY}}" > /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
         echo -e "Host ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}}\nIdentityFile /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /home/runner/.ssh/config 
         ssh-keyscan -H ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} > /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts
         cd myproject-infrastructure/ansible
         eval `ssh-agent -s`
         chmod 700 /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
         ansible-playbook -u ${{secrets.ANSIBLE_DEPLOY_USER}} -i hosts.yml setup-prod.yml
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found it

First basic setup of the action itself.

```
name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
```

Next add a job to run and checkout the repository in the first step.

```
jobs:
  run-playbooks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          token: ${{secrets.REPO_TOKEN}}
```

Next set up ssh correctly.

```
   - name: Setup ssh
   shell: bash
        run: |
         service ssh status
         eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

First of all you want to be sure that the ssh service is running. The ssh service was already running in my case.

However when I experimented with Docker I had to start the service manually at the first place like `service ssh start`. Next be sure that the `.shh` folder exists for your user and copy your private key to that folder. I have added a github secret to my repository where I saved my private key. In my case it is the `runner` user.

```
         mkdir -p /home/runner/.ssh/
         touch /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
         echo -e "${{secrets.SSH_KEY}}" > /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Make sure that your private key is protected. If not the ssh service wont accept working with it. To do so:

```
         chmod 700 /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Normally when you start a ssh connection you are asked if you want to save the host permanently as a known host. As we are running automatically we can't type in yes. If you don't answer the process will fail.

You have to prevent the process being interrupted by the prompt. To do so you add the host to the known_hosts file by yourself. You use `ssh-keyscan` for that. Unfortunately ssh-keyscan can produce output in differeny formats/types.
Simply using ssh-keyscan was not enough in my case. I had to add other type options to the command. The generated output has to be written to the `known_hosts` file in the `.ssh` folder of your user. In my case `/home/runner/.ssh/knwon_hosts`

So the next command is:

```
         ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa,ecdsa,ed25519 ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} >> /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Now you are almost there. Just call the ansible playbook command to run the ansible script. I ceated a new step where I changed the directory to the folder in my repository where my ansible files are saved.

```
 - name: Run ansible script
        shell: bash 
        run: |
          cd infrastructure/ansible
          ansible-playbook --private-key /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa -u ${{secrets.ANSIBLE_DEPLOY_USER}} -i hosts.yml setup-prod.yml
```

The complete file:

```
name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:
  
# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  run-playbooks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps: 
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          token: ${{secrets.REPO_TOKEN}}
      - name: Setup SSH 
        shell: bash
        run: |
         eval `ssh-agent -s`
         mkdir -p /home/runner/.ssh/
         touch /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
         echo -e "${{secrets.SSH_KEY}}" > /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
         chmod 700 /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa
         ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa,ecdsa,ed25519 ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}} >> /home/runner/.ssh/known_hosts
      - name: Run ansible script
        shell: bash 
        run: |
          service ssh status
          cd infrastructure/ansible
          cat setup-prod.yml
          ansible-playbook -vvv --private-key /home/runner/.ssh/id_rsa -u ${{secrets.ANSIBLE_DEPLOY_USER}} -i hosts.yml setup-prod.yml
```

Next enjoy...

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, without explaining why you have those errors, is to test and use [`actions/run-ansible-playbook`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-ansible-playbook) to run your playbook.

That way, you can test if the "sudo Password is missing" is missing in that configuration.

```yaml
- name: Run playbook
  uses: dawidd6/action-ansible-playbook@v2
  with:
    # Required, playbook filepath
    playbook: deploy.yml
    # Optional, directory where playbooks live
    directory: ./
    # Optional, SSH private key
    key: ${{secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}}
    # Optional, literal inventory file contents
    inventory: |
      [all]
      example.com

      [group1]
      example.com
    # Optional, SSH known hosts file content
    known_hosts: .known_hosts
    # Optional, encrypted vault password
    vault_password: ${{secrets.VAULT_PASSWORD}}
    # Optional, galaxy requirements filepath
    requirements: galaxy-requirements.yml
    # Optional, additional flags to pass to ansible-playbook
    options: |
      --inventory .hosts
      --limit group1
      --extra-vars hello=there
      --verbose
```

Comment: well actually I didn't want to use an action from external source for security reasons. When the source code changes it could get access to my files or credentials ‍♂️It probably won't but I think I am missing one little step to solve it.

Comment: But technically you are right it is a way you can achieve it. I should add without external action to the question maybe.

Comment: @Kerem OK,  I was not aware of that limitation. you could clone/fork https://github.com/dawidd6/action-ansible-playbook, push it to your own repository, review the code there, and therefore use your own action that way.